# dataset.train_test_split function does not work

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I have a dataframe with two fields: `text` and `labels`. I am trying to split this dataframe on training and testing set but for any reason I got the following error:

```
ValueError: External features info don't match the dataset:
Got
{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'labels': ClassLabel(num_classes=4, names=['false', 'partially false', 'true', 'other'], id=None)}
with type
struct<text: string, labels: int64>

but expected something like
{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'labels': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}
with type
```

The code I have is:

```
    dataset = ds.Dataset.from_pandas(df)
    dataset.features['labels'] = ds.ClassLabel(num_classes=4, names=['false', 'partially false', 'true', 'other'])
    train_data, test_data = dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.2).values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sklearn

```
X = df[["text"]]
y = df[["labels"]]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, 
        random_state=42)
```